# ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyconcorde, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Tags: python, git, spyder

I'm trying to install pyconcorde on window (https://github.com/jvkersch/pyconcorde). I have used this:

```
pip install -e git+https://github.com/jvkersch/pyconcorde.git#egg=pyconcorde
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR: Failed building editable for pyconcorde
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pyconcorde, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I'm working with Python 3.9.7 and on windows 11.

The systems suggests this but even after installing without the editable mode, the same problem persists:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem. This error appears to be caused by an incompatibility between compiling and linking libraries compiled with clang and GCC, that and the underlying Concorde library has no config for MacOSX.

1. Before running `pip install -e .` you must go into the `./pyconcorde/build/concorde` directory and manually configure it to build and compile Concorde.
2. It is important to unalias gcc, and then set the location of GCC `export CC="/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/12.2.0/bin/gcc-12"`
3. At this point, you can set the export QSOPTDIR=`pwd`/QSOPT and export CFLAGS="-g -O3 -arch x86_64", run configure and build.
4. Now you can go back and set the locations of Concorde, and QSOPT libraries and run pip install -e .
5. Load Python and use Concorde wrapper

A key aspect is to tell the python wrapper where Concorde and qsopt binaries are located...

```
export QSOPT_DIR=`pwd`/build/concorde/QSOPT
export CONCORDE_DIR=`pwd`/build/concorde/
```

### Resolution of Error:

```
git clone https://github.com/jvkersch/pyconcorde
cd pyconcorde
unalias gcc
export CC="/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/12.2.0/bin/gcc-12"
cd build/concorde
mkdir QSOPT;cd QSOPT
wget 'https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~bico/qsopt/downloads/codes/mac64/qsopt.gz'
wget 'https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~bico/qsopt/downloads/codes/mac64/qsopt.a.gz'
wget 'https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~bico/qsopt/downloads/codes/mac64/qsopt.h'
gunzip qsopt.a.gz
cd ..
export QSOPTDIR=`pwd`/QSOPT
export CFLAGS="-g -O3 -arch x86_64"
./configure --with-qsopt=$QSOPTDIR --host=darwin
make

# Check build succeeded
ls -la TSP/concorde

# go back to pyconcorde directory
cd ../../
export QSOPT_DIR=`pwd`/build/concorde/QSOPT
export CONCORDE_DIR=`pwd`/build/concorde/
pip install -e . 
Obtaining file:///Users/.../pyconcorde
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: cython>=0.22.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pyconcorde==0.1.0) (0.29.33)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages (from pyconcorde==0.1.0) (1.24.2)
Installing collected packages: pyconcorde
  Running setup.py develop for pyconcorde
Successfully installed pyconcorde-0.1.0

python3
Python 3.11.2 (main, Mar 24 2023, 00:31:37) [Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from concorde.tsp import TSPSolver
>>>
```